# Profile preference for auto download any files in firefox (different browsers also)

Tags: java, csv, pdf, selenium-webdriver

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(getFProfile());
        driver.get("http://www.energy.umich.edu/sites/default/files/pdf-sample.pdf");

        WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver(getFProfile());
        driver1.get("http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/SalesJan2009.csv");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static FirefoxProfile getFProfile()
{
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "${user.home}\\Downloads"); //C:\\download

    //For PDF
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");

    //For CSV
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");

    firefoxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

    firefoxProfile.setPreference("plugin.scan.Acrobat", "99.0");
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("plugin.scan.plid.all", false);

    return firefoxProfile;
}
```

> Above code is working for .pdf files only but for .csv prompt was displayed.
>   How can we auto save both using single profile preference setting.

please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below modified code for single profile:

```
 firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf, text/csv");
```

hope this helps !!

Comment: I've already tried with it, however it is not working for me, btw thanks for your response.